# Setting for Visual Studio 2008 to show more Recent Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is is possible to tweak Visual Studio 2008 to show more than the 6 default Recent Projects?

Comment: I wouldn't call that a tweak though... just a plain simple setting.

Comment: I agree with you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into Tools -> Options and under Environment/General you have Recent files group box. Second text box (_ items shown in recently used list) controls how many projects you will see. Just put e.g. 10 there.